# Reshaping pandas DataFrame from Meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

If I construct a pandas DataFrame as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 0.25)
y = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 0.25)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.sin(xx**2+yy**2)
df = pd.DataFrame(z, index=x, columns=y)
```

I now have a 41x41 DataFrame, where each value corresponds to an x,y pair.  I would like to reshape this DataFrame such that I have 3 columns (X,Y,Z) and 1681 rows with a new arbitrary index that ranges from 0-1680.

As a side note, I believe this would be the same as undoing a df.pivot('X','Y','Z') if my dataframe was already in the desired form, but I am unsure of how to accomplish this as well.

Comment: do a df.unstack() and see if that gives you what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not do it all in numpy?

```
>>> data = np.array([xx, yy, z]).reshape(3, -1).T
>>> data
array([[-5.01      , -5.01      , -0.0652361 ],
       [-4.76      , -5.01      , -0.59221922],
       [-4.51      , -5.01      ,  0.9936343 ], ...
```

Comment: This is the right answer to a different question. Either the question changes or the answer should not have been accepted (good answer, but doesn't address the dataframe point)

Answer (score 1):

The `unstack` will undo `pivot` [help on **pandas.unstack()**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

```python
df.unstack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0':'x','level_1':'y',0:'z'})
```

```
         x     y         z
0    -5.01 -5.01 -0.065236
1    -5.01 -4.76 -0.592219
2    -5.01 -4.51  0.993634
```

Answer (score 1):

You may reshape the multi-dim arrays to 1D arrays and create a dict, that will then easily convert to a well ordered dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 0.25)
y = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 0.25)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.sin(xx**2+yy**2)
NT = np.product(xx.shape)

data = {
    "x": np.reshape(xx,NT),
    "y": np.reshape(yy,NT),
    "z": np.reshape(zz,NT)
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

df
```

Will output:

```
    x   y   z
0   -5.01   -5.01   -0.065236
1   -4.76   -5.01   -0.592219
2   -4.51   -5.01   0.993634
3   -4.26   -5.01   -0.670288
4   -4.01   -5.01   -0.333011
... ... ... ...
1676    3.99    4.99    0.020503
1677    4.24    4.99    -0.893283
1678    4.49    4.99    0.880967
1679    4.74    4.99    -0.241402
1680    4.99    4.99    -0.448675
1681 rows × 3 columns
```